# Android Support Library v7 PreferenceFragment Preference Headers

Tags: android, preference

I have been able to implement a preference screen with the support library v7 using PreferenceFragmentCompat.

However I tried to implement PreferenceHeaders but I have not been able to find the equivalent of

```
 loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
```

in the preferenceactivity class for the PreferenceFragmentCompat.

Does anyone know how to implement PreferenceHeaders while using the PreferenceFragment or PreferenceFragment subclasses?

Comment: You might find your answer here, https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9kZ3SsXdT2T